# looks like this action is not supported

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I'm integration Paypal SDK `com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.3.0`.
All the configuration is done at the app level.
Here is the official documentation link:- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/

```
 val config = CheckoutConfig(
        application = application,
        clientId = AppConstants.getPayPalClientID(),
        environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
        returnUrl = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}://paypalpay",
        // currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD,
        userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW,

        settingsConfig = SettingsConfig(
            loggingEnabled = true
        )
    )
    PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config)
```

I'm getting the below error
[image]

Can any one help to solve this

Comment: Try searching the error here - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380972/paypal-android-native-checkout-sdk-invalid-client-id-or-redirect-uri-and-chec

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and spent almost a day.

We need to take care of below points:

- Properly follow each step of [Android-Client-side integration.](https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/native-checkout/android/)
- **My Apps & Credentials** -> Select/Edit your app. -> Check **Log in with PayPal**
- Make sure to check **Full name** and **Email**.
- Also make sure to provide **Privacy policy URL** and **User agreement URL**.

[image: login_with_paypal_checkbox_image]

- Also please note: After the page successfully opens, If you are testing with a sandbox environment, you must use a sandbox account to test transactions. The real user will not work. You can create/get sandbox accounts [from here.](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a browser issue. Crome, firefox or Duck Duck didn't go thru, butIt using Microsoft Edge went right thru , as weird as that is. So much for being anonymous.
At least you'll get access.